# How to change the element part of an array while iterating

Tags: ruby

An array `xs` consists of numbers from 0 to 9:

```
xs = [*0..9]
```

Test parity, and store result in place:

```
xs.map!(&:odd?)
puts xs.join(" ") 
# => false, true, ..., true
```

`xs` changed as expected. But I just want to change a part of the array

```
xs[5..-1].map!(&:odd?)
puts xs.join(" ")
# => 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I guess the `slice` operation returns a copy. Or some other reasons.

`xs[...] = xs[...].some_operation` is a solution, but is there any way to do this without assignment?

Comment: What do you mean by *"while iterating"*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to do this:

```
xs.fill(5..-1) { |i| xs[i].odd? }
#=> 0 1 2 3 4 true false true false true
```

Comment: This is so elegant. `fill` -- as if there's basically a method for everything in Ruby.

Comment: It looks elegant, but it does something else. `fill` passes the element's *index* to the block, not the element itself.

Comment: @Stefan  Thanks for pointing out the mistake.  Have updated the answer